# LINQ how to Group data by date day and month and year

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

I created a method that group data using date (day, month, year) .

This is my code:

```
private IEnumerable<StatsticsVm> GetStatsticsPerDay(StatsticsQueryModel sqm)
{

    var messages = GetMessagesByDateAndIU(sqm);

    IEnumerable<StatsticsVm> messagesCountPerDay =

        from year in Enumerable.Range(sqm.From.Year, sqm.To.Year - sqm.From.Year + 1)
        from month in Enumerable.Range(1, 12)
        from day in Enumerable.Range(1, 31)
        let key = new { Year = year, Month = month, Day = day }
        join message in messages on key
        equals new
        {
            message.ObservationDateTime.Year,
            message.ObservationDateTime.Month,
            message.ObservationDateTime.Day
        } into g
        select new StatsticsVm()
        {
            Label = key.Day + "/" + key.Month + "/" + key.Year,
            MessagesCount = g.Count()
        };

    return messagesCountPerDay;

}
```

My question is: this method have a bug, the bug is the result is always included 12 months and 31 days i want the result to be just as the filter.

For example if I just want the data from day 1 to day 15 I always got group from day 1 to day 31. And same with months.

Note: I also want all days that included in my filter even if the day have 0 message. And that is already done in this method.

Comment: You're saying that you want all the days included, then why is having all months and days a problem? What does "i want the result to be just as the filter" mean?

Comment: i meant that i want just the (years,months,days)  even if these days have no messages. and the bug here is even if my filter is from month 3 to month 12 the result is always from month 1 to month 12 and from day 1 to day 31. i hope that i make it clear now .

Comment: from day to 13 or 31? It's a bit unclear, you should pass to the method min and max month along side min and max day

Comment: I don't understand, I've just tried your code and does exactly what you want, including the filtering and the outer join. Or maybe your problem is that you are not using the sqm for the month and days?

Comment: @OfirWinegarten yes this is my problem and i'm trying to solve it now .

Comment: What's wrong with:  `from month in Enumerable.Range(sqm.From.Month, sqm.To.Month- sqm.From.Month+ 1)
        from day in Enumerable.Range(sqm.From.Day, sqm.To.Day- sqm.From.Day+ 1)`. Although this will give you bad dates like `31/02/2016`

Comment: @OfirWinegarten also it will give me a bad data if i query multiple years.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think i finally got you.

Your issue is with the way you try to create `DateTime` range.

The correct way is like this:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + sqm.To.Subtract(sqm.From).Days)
          .Select(offset => sqm.From.AddDays(offset))
```

This will give you the following code:

```
private IEnumerable<StatsticsVm> GetStatsticsPerDay(StatsticsQueryModel sqm)
{

    var messages = GetMessagesByDateAndIU(sqm);
    var dateRange = Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + sqm.To.Subtract(sqm.From).Days)
                              .Select(offset => sqm.From.AddDays(offset));

    IEnumerable<StatsticsVm> messagesCountPerDay =
        from date in dateRange
        join message in messages on date
        equals message.ObservationDateTime into g
        select new StatsticsVm()
        {
            Label = date.Day + "/" + date.Month + "/" + date.Year,
            MessagesCount = g.Count()
        };

    return messagesCountPerDay;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can see what you're trying to do is take the messages between the date range, group them by date and take the count for each date.

```
from messages in  message
where (messages .ObservationDateTime < sqm.To) 
           && (messages .ObservationDateTime > sqm.From))
group orders by EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(m.ObservationDateTime) 
           into dateMessages
select new StatsticsVm()
    {
        Label = dateMessages.key.Day + "/" + dateMessages.key.Month + "/" + dateMessages.key.Year,
        MessagesCount = dateMessages.Count()
    };
```

Comment: but what if the is date with 0 without messages , i want it also be in the result with 0 count.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work for you:

```
private IEnumerable<StatsticsVm> GetStatsticsPerDay(StatsticsQueryModel sqm)
{
    var messages = GetMessagesByDateAndIU(sqm);

    var f = new DateTime(sqm.From.Year, 1, 1);
    var t = new DateTime(sqm.To.Year + 1, 1, 1);

    var lookup = messages.ToLookup(x => x.ObservationDateTime.Date);

    IEnumerable<StatsticsVm> messagesCountPerDay =
        from n in Enumerable.Range(0, t.Subtract(f).Days)
        let day = f.AddDays(n)
        select new StatsticsVm()
        {
            Label = day.ToString(@"d/m/y"),
            MessagesCount = lookup[day].Count()
        };

    return messagesCountPerDay;
}
```